# Synonymize [php-mongodb] to [mongodb-php]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [php-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-mongodb) and [mongodb-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-php) ostensibly refer to the same thing.

The latter is older, has more questions, and a more complete tag wiki.

[php-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-mongodb) should be synonymized to [mongodb-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-php).

Comment: It will be hilarious if Mongo provides a php library (mongodb-php) and someone wrote a php library for mongodb (php-mongodb) making both different but similarly named products.